How to initialize Future List DataRow
I need to initialize
Future<List<DataRow>> myrow = [];

I need to construct a table based on a future list.
Right now, I get the message:

A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<List>'

Thank you

Future<List<DataRow>> myrow = Future.value([]);


When you got a function that return a Future<List>, this mean two things:
First, the function is asynchronous and may not return immediately ans second the type of the return value is List.
So if you have a function prototype like this one:
Future<List<DataRow>> myFunction() { ... }

you have to get the return value to do this:
List<DataRow> myrow = [];
myrow = await myFunction();

The await keyword instruct to wait for myFunction return.
You can also use .then in order to wait myFunction completion :
myFunction()
.then((value) => {
    myrow = value; // In this case value type is List<DataRow>
});


The error occurs because Future<List<DataRow>> expects a future (an asynchronous value) rather than a direct list. To initialize it properly, you need to assign a future or use an asynchronous function to fetch or construct the data

I am sorry. I do not understand. Could you please provide an example.
